# How to made a webservice been called each 2 minutes

Tags: java, linux, web-services, logging, glassfish

I need to check the GlassFish log file in a linux server and check if its has an specific error I send an E-mail for me. There is a way to me make a webservice that do it be execute each 2 minutes? How could I do it? I am working with Java and GlassFish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java EE 6 o Java EE 7, you can try the following:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MonitorBean {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/2", second = "0", persistent = false)
    public void searchErrorInLog() {
        // Read the log file
        // Looking for some error string
        // If found, send mail
    }

}
```

Maybe you should save the time of the last event to avoid repetition. Being a single instance, maintains the state while the application server is running. Another solution is to use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

See also:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html
- [Using the Timer Service - The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)
- [Quartz 1.6 Scheduler Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/)

Comment: Thanks! It`ll resolve... I don`t Know why somebody voted negative for you... just put second = "0" instead second = "*"

Answer (score 1):

It seems overkill to me to go through GlassFish to make stateless scans of its own log file every so often. Unless you have constraint restricting access to the server I'd set up a separate process such as http://www.crypt.gen.nz/logsurfer/ to monitor the log file in real-time with much lower overhead (and less effort on your side :).